# No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency when pass parameter to the Bean

Tags: java, spring

I am studing Spring and trying to create bean and pass parameter to it.
My bean in Spring configuration file looks like:

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public InputFile inputFile (String path)
{
    InputFile inputFile = new InputFile();
    inputFile.setPath(path);
    return inputFile;
}
```

InputFile class is:

```
public class InputFile {
    String path = null;
    public InputFile(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
    public InputFile() {

    }
    public String getPath() {
       return path;
    }
    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

and in main method i have:

```
InputFile inputFile = (InputFile) ctx.getBean("inputFile", "C:\\");
```

`C:\\` - is a parameter which i am trying to pass in.

I run application and receive root exception:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

What i did wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass a value to your parameter then only you can access the bean. This is what the message given in the Exception.

Use @Value annotation above the method declaration and pass a value to it.

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
@Value("\\path\\to\\the\\input\\file")
public InputFile inputFile (String path)
{
    InputFile inputFile = new InputFile();
    inputFile.setPath(path);
    return inputFile;
}
```

Also while accessing this bean you need to access it using the below code

```
InputFile inputFile = (InputFile) ctx.getBean("inputFile");
```

Comment: But how to change path during application executing? E.g. in one place of app i want to create bean with one path and with another path in other place of app.

Comment: Also i have read about PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, but it is not suitable in my case, because i want to use bean in different place of program with different paths. May be spring doen't allow it because set up context before application running....

Comment: If you want to create objects on runtime. It would not be possible. Since Spring takes care of Injection and you  need to pass the dependencies while creation of the object

Comment: Do i need to create separate bean with another path?

Comment: Yes you would require to create another bean with another path.